# Count consecutive preceding elements in DolphinDB

Tags: count, dolphindb

| Volume | f | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 0 | no volume before 10 |
| 7 | 0 | no smaller volume before 7 |
| 13 | 2 | Both 10 and 7 are smaller than 13 |
| 6 | 0 | 13 is larger than 6 |
| 4 | 0 | 6 is larger than 4 |
| 8 | 2 | Both 6 and 4 are smaller than 8 |
| 7 | 0 | 8 is larger than 7 |
| 3 | 0 | 7 is larger than 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 is smaller than 4 |

As shown in the above table, I’d like to obtain the f column based on volume in DolphinDB.
Suppose the current volume is t, the desired output f is the count of volumes that meet the following conditions:

1. There are consecutive elements in volume column that are less than t
2. The last volume of the consecutive elements is the preceding volume
   before t;

The calculation principle in detail is illustrated in the explanation column.

I tried for-loop but it didn't work. Does DolphinDB support any other functions to obtain the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
t = table(1..10 as volume) tmp = select volume, iif(deltas(volume)>0, rowNo(volume), NULL) as flag from t tmp.bfill!() select volume, cumrank(volume) from tmp context by flag
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?